# Markers in bison

Tags: parsing, bison

Suppose you want to add a semantic action in a middle of rule, so you replace:

```
S->AB
```

with:

```
S->AMB
M->epsilon { //do something }
```

Why is that necessary? What would happen if instead I would just write:

```
S->A { //do something } B
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no difference with the parser -- writing the action in the middle of the rule is syntactic sugar for creating a new epsilon rule with the action.  Actions are triggered by reductions in the parser, so there needs to be a rule to be reduced associated with the action.  Bison does the conversion automatically for you.

The only difference is with the meaning of `$1`... in the action.  With the embedded action the base point in the value stack that the index computes off of will be different -- based on the start of the containing rule rather than the epsilon rule.